# Controller is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angularjs-module

I'm trying to use the Angularjs-UI Modal into my application and I'm a little confused as to what goes where. I have a button for new groups which calls a model, the models controller is in another file. I'm trying to call the newGroupCtrl within the groupCtrl but it's returning undefined.

HTML for new group button:

```
<button type="button" class="delGroupBtn" ng-click="newGroup()">New Group</button>
```

In my groupCtrl I have this `newgroup()` function:

```
    $scope.newGroup = function (){
        var modalForm = '/Style%20Library/projects/spDash/app/partials/newGroup.html';
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: modalForm,
            backdrop: true,
            windowClass: 'modal',
            controller: newGroupCtrl,
            resolve:{
                newGroup:function (){
                    return  $scope.newGroup;
                }
            }
        });
    };
```

Then I've got my newGroup.html (the modal) which is where the user would enter the groups name, description, owner:

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <form>
        <label for="groupName">Group Name:
            <input id="groupName" type="text" ng-model='newGroup.name'>
        </label>
        <hr>
        <label for="groupDesc">Group Description:
            <input id="groupDesc" type="text" ng-model='newGroup.desc'>
        </label>
        <hr>
        <label for="groupOwner">Group Name:
            <select id="groupOwner" type="text" ng-model=''></select>
        </label>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
            <button class="btn primary-btn" type="button" ng-click="newGroup()">Create</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Here's the newGroupCtrl:

```
spApp.controller('newGroupCtrl',
    function newGroupCtrl($scope, $modalInstance){

        $scope.newGroup = {
            name:null,
            desc:null
        };

        $scope.submit = function(){
            console.log('creating new group');
            console.log(newGroup);
            $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        }
        $scope.cancel = function (){
            $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        };

        $modalInstance.result.then(function (){
            groupService.newGroup($scope.newGroup);
        }, function (){
            console.log('No new group created.');
        });
    }
);
```

I've injected the group and newGroup controllers with my group service which is where I'm trying to get the information from the model to the groupService function to make the AJAX call to my server and create the new group. It seems like I'm repeating myself in both controllers with the $model.open({})

Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mYFnsOJP1tPazcXuomt0?p=info)

Comment: Comparing with the docs at http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal it looks fine. So it's probably in the implementation. Your plunker is no help there. Please refactor to it runs or reproduces the same result you see in your test environment.

Comment: Not sure if this is your main issue, but the modalInstance.result.then should be in groupCtrl, not newGroupCtrl (with no $). Also you probably want to call close() rather than dismiss() in your submit callback. It looks like you're trying to call the parent controller method from inside the modal controller. What you want to do is pass data back from the modal via $modalInstance.close(), and then have the parent controller act on that data when the modalInstance.result is resolved.

Comment: Do you mean something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Qqmk5/ I've also changed things up a bit. Instead of having a seperate file for the newGroupCtrl, I just wrote out the function in the controller parameter for the modal. I couldn't figure out how to reference the controller js file within a controller. Now the modal actually shows up which is good, but I'm strill trying to figure out how to pass the modal data to my service.

Answer (score 0):

#### When controller is defined as part of the angular module (using `.controller()` method) than it must be referenced as a string.

#### When controller is defined as a simple JS function, then it must be referenced through a variable.

In you modal configuration object, you referenced `newGroupCtrl` as a variable, not as a string.

```js
...
controller: newGroupCtrl,
...
```

vs

```js
...
controller: 'newGroupCtrl',
...
```

But your controller is defined with `angular.module().controller()`:

```js
spApp.controller('newGroupCtrl',
    function newGroupCtrl($scope, $modalInstance){...})
```

To fix, you need to put the name of the controller in quotes OR define the controller as a simple standalone JS function.

So, it's either this:

```js
...
controller: 'newGroupCtrl',
...

spApp.controller('newGroupCtrl',
    function newGroupCtrl($scope, $modalInstance){...})
```

OR this:

```js
...
controller: newGroupCtrl,
...

function newGroupCtrl($scope, $modalInstance){...}
```

Comment: What if I want to have newGroupCtrl by itself in it's own file. Right now to get it working instead of using a variable I simply put all the modal controller functions within my main controller but I'd like to keep those seperate. Here's what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/NbH8M/1/

Comment: Whether your controller is in different file or not has nothing to do with the way it's being referenced in modal config.

Comment: Don't I have to somehow inject that newGroupCtrl into the groupCtrl? I'm not sure how to reference the controller if it's in another file.